# Can T(n) = 2T(n/4)+ n^3 + n^2 be solved using Master Theorem?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, data-structures, master-theorem

Can the following recursion:

T(n) = 2T(n/4)+ n^3  + n^2

be solved using Master Theorem?

It meets the preconditions that f(n) is positive, a>=1, b>1, and the difference between (n^3 + n^2) and n/2 (logarithm base 4 of 2) is polynomial. Would f(n)=O(n^3)?

Comment: There's preconditions for the Master theorem in each of the cases. Which case do you think applies here, and what would the preconditions be in that case? Does the relation meet those preconditions? It's fine to ask homework questions here, but it's better to show that you've done some work on them yourself, and are stuck at a specific point.

Comment: I did check it against the preconditions but I haven't found any examples of recursions with an addition of two polynomials so I don't know if it can be solved with it. In the case it can, I already worked it out using f(n)=O(n^3).

Comment: Yes, you're in case 3: c_crit is 1/2, f(n) = Omega(n^c) for example for c=2 and c>c_crit. So T(n) = Theta(f(n)) = Theta(n^3).

Comment: Perfect, thank you